# Build Tools Maven or Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

Looking for a clarification:

When we add a third party dependencies in Maven or Gradle project, are those precompiled dependencies?

if yes, then what if there are compiled on higher version of Java, and my local setup is on lower machine?

if No, is it something like locally they are compiled at the of compilation and placed in the classpath?

I am getting below issue while running gladle clean build on java 8, Note selenium is the third party dependency I am using.

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
                          ^
  bad class file: C:\Users\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-api\4.17.0\643b9\selenium-api-4.17.0.jar(org/openqa/selenium/By.class)
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

so above error resolves when I change project sdk to Java 21 and gradle jvm to SDK 21.

Comment: Yes. Then they don't work. See also [the central repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/).

Comment: if you work locally with Java 19 and one of those libraries is compiled with Java 21, your compilation will fail for obvious reasons

Comment: so did you mean all the jars are precompiled?

Comment: @HarishAlgat yes

Comment: can you show all the code please , and maven file

Comment: @Stultuske can you please explain me the role of build tool then? like how they resolve dependencies?

Comment: @HarishAlgat they don't. that's the developers job.

Comment: The given error message tells you that you have to use JDK 11 at minium based on the version 55.0...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history and yes in Java jar files are already compiled (they contain the compiled class files) and are being consumed in that way. That's the basic concept of Java (compile once run anywhere via the JVM)..

Comment: @HarishAlgat "how they resolve dependencies" that's too broad a question and a different one. Try reading the documentation of the tool you are interested. Both Maven and Gradle document how they resolve dependencies. If you don't understand something post an specific new question.

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives you the answer. The error indicates that a class in a library was compiled with a newer version of Java than the one you are using for building the project. That should tell you that the library was effectively precompiled outside your project.

It is not Gradle or Maven responsibility to know or care if libraries are compiled with which Java version. Those build tools for Java only care about retrieving the dependencies from repositories, adding them to your project build and execute the compiler. The error happens inside the compiler execution. That's up to the user. You need to select versions of dependencies that are compatible with your project and compiler.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a dependency to your project, you are getting a jar file that was compiled by whatever JDK that lib supports. You need to use versions of libraries that are compatible with the JDK you are using in your project. You most likely need to downgrade the version of the 3rd party lib you are including.